# Random background colour picker for tumblr

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

I've got this in my code, which should select a random background colour every refresh, but i can't see what's wrong with my document.write

```
var bgcolorlist=new Array("#ff871b", "#15efa1", "#51ddff", "#ff1b6c", "#000000")



document.write('<meta name="color:Background" content='+background=bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)] + '>')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to add an ID to your **body** and then use this code:

```
<script>
    var bgcolorlist=new Array("background: #ff871b", "background: #15efa1", "background: #51ddff", "background: #ff1b6c", "background: #000000");
    var color = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
    var d = document.getElementById("your-body"); 
    d.setAttribute("style", color);
</script>
```

As far as I know, Tumblr allows you to use jQuery, which is way easier than pure Javascript. If you have jQuery added to your code, just do:

```
<script>
    var bgcolorlist=new Array("background: #ff871b", "background: #15efa1", "background: #51ddff", "background: #ff1b6c", "background: #000000");
    var color = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
    $('body').css('backgroundColor', color);
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, my code knowledge is still fairly primitive. What would I add to my css to make this work? Thanks for the fixed code and the jQuery!

Comment: Inside your HTML template on Tumblr HTML editor, search (CRTL+F) for <body (notice, don't close the tag). And then add an ID to it.

For example: <body id="your-body">.

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolons after each line.

Additionally, why are you seeing the background color with a meta tag?

Use this line instead:

```
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = bgcolorlist[Math.floor(Math.random()*bgcolorlist.length)];
```

Comment: He is using meta name probably because of Tumblr HTML editor.